# Drop columns tha thave a header but all rows are empty Python 3 & Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, drop

I just could not figure this one out:

```
df.dropna(axis = 1, how="all").dropna(axis= 0 ,how="all")
```

All headers have data. How can I exclude the headers form a `df.dropna(how="all")` command.
I am afraid this is going to be trivial, but help me out guys.

Thanks,
Levi

Comment: Can you please clarify your question further?  Are you trying to drop columns that contain only NaN, or columns with more than some x Nan values?  Do you also want to drop rows with NaN values or only rows with more than y NaN values?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the clarifying question. I would like to drop rows that have NaN ONLY. Further columns that have NaN values ONLY.  In other words, if there is one value other than NaN then the row/ column remains. BUT every column has a header and I don't want the headers to be taken into account. A Column can be deleted despite the header if all else is NaN. Hope this adds clarity to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as I understand what you want is as follows:

- drop any column where all rows contain NaN
- drop any row in which one or more NaN appear

So for example, given a dataframe df like:

```
    Id  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
0   1   25.0    A   NaN 6
1   2   15.0    B   NaN 7
2   3   23.0    C   NaN 8
3   4   5.0 D   NaN 9
4   5   NaN E   NaN 10
```

convert the dataframe by:

```
df.dropna(axis = 1, how="all", inplace= True)
df.dropna(axis = 0, how='all', inplace= True)
```

which yields:

```
    Id  Col1    Col2    Col4
0   1   25.0    A   6
1   2   15.0    B   7
2   3   23.0    C   8
3   4   5.0     D   9
4   5   NaN     E   10
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution you have submitted. I appreciate your time. A short correction: Drop any row that has NaN values only. (One value "saves" the column and the row. That one value cannot be the column header )

Comment: @Levente, just updated the results to correctly show the yield from my solution.

Comment: Hi @itprorh66 thank you for the solution. I upvoted your input but it does not show due to my low rep. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help